MongoDB error : Pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field
I am new to mongodb and trying out aggregation.
 db.aggregate([
  { '$match': {} },
  {
    '$group': { _id: [Object] },
    '$project': {
      resource_subcategory: '$_id.resource_subcategory',
      resource_usage: 1
    }
  }
]）

I get the error:

A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

I couldn't find a good explanation of the reason in SO.

You're just passing an empty object to $match. It's not like with find, where {} matches anything. You need to pass it something.

If you do want to match everything you can just remove the $match. An aggregate pipeline will start with all documents in the collection.

$group and $project need to be their own stages. You have them as one pipeline stage.

$match is fine like that, pointless but fine.

It should be like this:
db.aggregate([
  { '$match': {} },
  { '$group': { _id: [Object] } },
  { '$project': {
      resource_subcategory: '$_id.resource_subcategory',
      resource_usage: 1
    }
  }
]）

However { '$match': {} } is pointless, it selects all documents. You can skip it.
resource_usage is not part of group accumulator, thus it will be always empty, i.e. it's also pointless.
